# how to get the original SelectItem value after the user's choice?

Tags: autosuggest, oracle-adf

I create input text with auto suggest items

```
<af:inputText label="Seller" id="Seller"
              valueChangeListener="#{managedBeanTest.OnChangeSeller}" autoSubmit="true"
              autoComplete="on">
  <af:autoSuggestBehavior suggestedItems="#{managedBeanTest.OnSearchSellers}"/>
</af:inputText>
```

set SelectItem value to my class Item

```
public class Test
{
    public static class Item
    {
        public Item(int id, String code, String name) { ... }
        public String toString() { ... }
    }

    public List<SelectItem> OnSearchSellers(String search)
    {
        ResultSet rs;
        ...
        List<SelectItem> result = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

        while (rs.next())
            result.add(new SelectItem(new Item(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3))));

        return result;
    }

    public void OnChangeSeller(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent)
    {
        Object newVal = valueChangeEvent.getNewValue();

        if(newVal != null)
          System.out.println("OnChangeSeller: " + newVal.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

But in OnChangeSeller i've got only java.lang.String. 
How I can get original selected item value (Item class) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually passing a Java object to a HTML page doesn't work as the browser only shows String values (have a look at the rendered HTML page). So what you need to do is to pass the index of the object as a value. Then when the user selects a value you take the index and lookup the list for the real object you are interested in.

Frank

Comment: sad. Why then Object in the SelectItem constructor?

Comment: Not sad at all because you are able to work with the object on the server side. If the support was only for a single string value you probably would think of strategies to encode a value so that you can identify an object based on the encoded value. Also you may want to have a look at the valuePassThru property of the selectChoice as it allows you to change the behavior for non ADF bound lists

Answer (score 0):

doesn't valueChangeEvent.getOldValue()
not have this?

Comment: old value is also String or null :(

Answer (score 0):

*"doesn't valueChangeEvent.getOldValue() not have this?"*

Yes, if you use ADF binding. In this case the returned value is the index of the list